# How do i manage the Facebook Comments?

Tags: facebook-apps

1) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator

2) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/

Hello.

I have configured the Facebook Comments & added it to my website as per link (1).

I have got this line in the head section of my website..

However, when i go to the tools area (link 2), it says that i am not the manager / admin of any comments area.

Can anyone advise

A) How do i "verify" with facebook that my website is configued correctly for comments ?

B) how do i confirm my "id" ? Ive been to one page that has given me the above ID number, but its not on 'facebook' itself. its on an external website.

Comment: EDIT - Ive added meta property="fb:admins" content="814784042"  to the HEAD section (also with angled brackets)

Comment: EDIT 2 :- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/ - Ive created an AP ID in "my apps" - It appears that i can manage my comments now - however there is no 'manage' link in my actual website. I just need to wait for someone to comment & see what happens...